BBC2 Children's Math show early 2000s
It was a bbc 2 show, late 90s/early 2000s about Maths/Numbers/Money and I remember it being themed around a royal court and would end with an orphan boy singing a song which included the lyric 'if you take care of the pennies then the pennies will look after you'.
It had a lot of counting in it.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

Indeed more details are always welcome in ID questions, though I'll admit that this one is actually fairly detailed (and easily recognizable), it just doesn't look it because it's short.

You're after the educational kids show Megamaths, which aired on BBC2 in 1996-2001 and taught about money in 1998. Here's a clip where that 'orphan boy' sings over the closing credits, "Look after pennies and the pennies will look after you" (it's around 08:33):



